# Input field in MUI-datatable

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable, mui-x-data-grid

Is it possible to add input fields to MUI-datatable? I want the user to be able to modify data in the MUI-datatable. However the `customBodyRender` does not work for me.

```
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";
import {MuiThemeProvider} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';

const columns = [
        {
            name: 'name',
            label: translationState['label.name'],
            options: {
                sort: true,
            },
            customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {  
                return (
                    <TextField required defaultValue={value} 
                      onChange={event => updateValue(event.target.value)}
                      InputProps={{
                        readOnly: false, //I tried to make sure it is not readOnly
                      }}
                    />
                )
            }
        },... some other columns]
```

The field is still disabled.
[mui-datatables documentation](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables)

I have tried to do it based on [this example](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/blob/master/examples/component/index.js).

```
const columns = [
      {
        name: "Name",
        options: {
          filter: false,
          customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => (
            <FormControlLabel
              label=""
              value={value}
              control={<TextField value={value} />}
              onChange={event => updateValue(event.target.value)}
            />
          )
        }
      },
```

But I cannot make it work.

Is `MUI-datatables` only for displaying data? Should I use `@mui/x-data-grid` insted of datatables to allow user to modify data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the closing parenthesis of `options` on the wrong line...

```
const columns = [
    {
        name: 'name',
        label: translationState['label.name'],
        options: {
            sort: true,
        // }, closing parenthesis at the wrong line
            customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {  
                return (
                    <TextField required defaultValue={value} 
                      onChange={event => updateValue(event.target.value)}
                      InputProps={{
                          readOnly: false,
                      }}
                    />
                )
            }
        } // correct position of `options` closing parenthesis
    },... some other columns
```

`customBodyRender` is one attribute of `options`, so it must be within its parentheses.